# VS2013: Potential issue with optimizing move semantics for classes with vector members?

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, vector, visual-studio-2013, move-semantics

I compiled the following code on VS2013 (using "Release" mode optimization) and was dismayed to find the assembly of `std::swap(v1,v2)` was not the same as `std::swap(v3,v4)`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
class WRAPPED_VEC
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    void push_back(T value) { m_vec.push_back(value); }

    WRAPPED_VEC() = default;

    WRAPPED_VEC(WRAPPED_VEC&& other) : m_vec(std::move(other.m_vec)) {}

    WRAPPED_VEC& operator =(WRAPPED_VEC&& other)
    {
        m_vec = std::move(other.m_vec);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> m_vec;
};


int main (int, char *[])
{
    WRAPPED_VEC<int> v1, v2;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v1), 10, std::rand);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v2), 10, std::rand);
    std::swap(v1, v2);

    std::vector<int> v3, v4;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v3), 10, std::rand);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v4), 10, std::rand);
    std::swap(v3, v4);

    return 0;
}
```

The `std::swap(v3, v4)` statement turns into "perfect" assembly.  How can I achieve the same efficiency for `std::swap(v1, v2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of points to be made here.

**1.**  If you don't know for absolutely certain that your way of calling `swap` is equivalent to the "correct" way of calling `swap`, you should always use the "correct" way:

```
using std::swap;
swap(v1, v2);
```

**2.** A really convenient way to look at the assembly for something like calling `swap` is to put the call by itself in a test function.  That makes it easy to isolate the assembly:

```
void
test1(WRAPPED_VEC<int>& v1, WRAPPED_VEC<int>& v2)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(v1, v2);
}

void
test2(std::vector<int>& v1, std::vector<int>& v2)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(v1, v2);
}
```

As it stands, `test1` will call `std::swap` which looks something like:

```
template <class T>
inline
swap(T& x, T& y) noexcept(is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
                          is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value)
{
    T t(std::move(x));
    x = std::move(y);
    y = std::move(t);
}
```

And this is fast.  It will use `WRAPPED_VEC`'s move constructor and move assignment operator.

However `vector` swap is even faster:  It swaps the `vector`'s 3 pointers, and if `std::allocator_traits<std::vector<T>::allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value` is true (and it is not), also swaps the allocators.  If it is false (and it is), and if the two allocators are equal (and they are), then everything is ok.  Otherwise Undefined Behavior happens.

To make `test1` identical to `test2` performance-wise you need:

```
friend
void
swap(WRAPPED_VEC<int>& v1, WRAPPED_VEC<int>& v2)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(v1.m_vec, v2.m_vec);
}
```

One interesting thing to point out:

In your case, where you are always using `std::allocator<T>`, the `friend` function is always a win.  However if your code allowed other allocators, possibly those with state, which might compare unequal, and which might have `propagate_on_container_swap::value` false (as `std::allocator<T>` does), then these two implementations of `swap` for `WRAPPED_VEC` diverge somewhat:

**1.**  If you rely on `std::swap`, then you take a performance hit, but you will never have the possibility to get into undefined behavior.  Move construction on `vector` is always well-defined and O(1).  Move assignment on `vector` is always well-defined and can be either O(1) or O(N), and either noexcept(true) or noexcept(false).

If `propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is false, and if the two allocators involved in a move assignment are unequal, `vector` move assignment will become O(N) and noexcept(false).  Thus a `swap` using `vector` move assignment will inherit these characteristics.  However, no matter what, the behavior is always well-defined.

**2.**  If you overload `swap` for `WRAPPED_VEC`, thus relying on the `swap` overload for `vector`, then you expose yourself to the possibility of undefined behavior if the allocators compare unequal and have `propagate_on_container_swap::value` equal to false.  But you pick up a potential performance win.

As always, there are engineering tradeoffs to be made.  This post is meant to alert you to the nature of those tradeoffs.

PS:  The following comment is purely stylistic.  All capital names for class types are generally considered poor style.  It is tradition that all capital names are reserved for macros.

Comment: Thanks.  I really appreciate the discussion on the engineering tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that `std::swap` does have an optimized overload for type `std::vector<T>` (see right click -> go to definition). To make this code work fast for your wrapper, follow instructions found on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) about std::swap:

> std::swap may be specialized in namespace std for user-defined types,
>   but such specializations are not found by ADL (the namespace std is
>   not the associated namespace for the user-defined type). The expected
>   way to make a user-defined type swappable is to provide a non-member
>   function swap in the same namespace as the type: see [Swappable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable) for
>   details.